# Is there a way in Apex to search for picklist based on recordtype dynamically in apex without using any external library?

Tags: apex, metadata-api, picklist

Is there a way in Apex to search for picklist based on recordtype in apex without using any external library?

I know that we can capture the list of picklists from a wired function in lwc but that is hardwired to a specific object( I need that to be dynamic).

I know that it's possible to get it through VF page but that is a old way of getting the result.

I see that it's possible to do with the Metadata class but not sure how to get the data.

Answer (score 1):

getPicklistValues is not necessarily hardwired, you can use it as follows:

```
    @track recordTypeId;
    @track picklistFieldName;

    @wire(getPicklistValues, { recordTypeId: "$recordTypeId", fieldApiName: "$picklistFieldName" })
    propertyOrFunction;


    somefunction(){
        ...
        this.recordTypeId = someRecordTypeId;
        this.picklistFieldName = "SomeObject.SomeField__c";
    }
```

You can find an objects default recordtype id or it's recordtypes by using [getObjectInfo](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reference_wire_adapters_object_info) which can dynamically get any object in the same way.